# How can I change navigationbar color when using TWA or custom tabs?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, chrome-custom-tabs, trusted-web-activity

I am using TWA . It is all Ok .But how can I change navigation bar color? I tried to change the app theme but no effect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change android's NavBar and StatusBar colors by, respectively, changing fields `background_color` and `theme_color` on your app.webmanifest.

[image: Example]
Notice that this color can be overridden by the HTML `theme-color` `<meta>` and `background-color` `<meta>` elements.
[You can learn more at web.dev documentation.](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/web-app-manifest/#recommended-fields)